# Using Keras to build a linear classifier

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I need to create a model over a set of 10 categories.  It should be a single layer linear classifier with a softmax activation function.  I have written some code from various tutorials, but it doesn't seem to give me the results that I need.

This is the function I wrote:

```
def build_classifier():
    model = models.Sequential([
    layers.Input(shape=(2,)),
    layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax'),
    ])
    return model
```

It gets called by:

```
newModel = build_classifier()
newModel.summary()
```

The data and labels are defined as:

```
labels = ['a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']

data = keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
```

I keep getting the following result:

```
Model: "sequential_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 3         
=================================================================
Total params: 3
Trainable params: 3
Non-trainable params: 0
```

But I need to get:

```
Model: "linear_classifier"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 3072)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 10)                30730     
=================================================================
Total params: 30,730
Trainable params: 30,730
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I'm especially unsure of how to go from the sequential_3 to the linear_classifier, as I can only seem to find this `models.Sequential` and not a version for a linear classifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this

```
import tensorflow as tf

def build_classifier():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(32,32,3)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(name='flatten'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='linear', name='dense'),
    ], name='linear_classifier')
    return model

model = build_classifier()
model.summary()

Model: "linear_classifier"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 3072)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 10)                30730     
=================================================================
Total params: 30,730
Trainable params: 30,730
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: That seems to work for the information, but it doesn't seem to change what the model is classified as.  The first line in the summaries have been `Model: "sequential_3"`(my original), `Model: "sequential_2"` (your version when softmax was changed to linear), but I need it to be `Model: "linear_classifier"`.  Do you know how to change it to that?

Comment: I receive `Model: "sequential_3"` with that code

Comment: That just a name. Can you ensure what's the last layer you want? Is it `dense_4 (Dense)    (None, 1) ` or `dense_4 (Dense)   (None, 10) ` ?

Comment: The name makes so much sense!  Thank you!  Are the flatten and dense layers where it says `flatten_6` and `dense_5` also names then?  
The last layer that I want is `dense (Dense)                (None, 10)                30730 `

Comment: I see that they are!  It's working now!  Thank you!